# Automated GnuPG key generation during maven deployment does not export secret key

Tags: java, maven, gnupg, gitlab-ci

I have a oss pom based java project hosted in gitlab - [JBus](https://gitlab.com/dizitart/jbus). I want to setup automated deployment to central maven repository via gitlab-ci-runner.

One problem I am currently facing is automated gpg key generation in gitlab ci server. I followed the below steps

```
$cat >foo <<EOF
     %echo Generating a basic OpenPGP key
     Key-Type: DSA
     Key-Length: 1024
     Subkey-Type: ELG-E
     Subkey-Length: 1024
     Name-Real: Anindya Chatterjee
     Name-Comment: with stupid passphrase
     Name-Email: anidotnet- at -gmail.com
     Expire-Date: 0
     Passphrase: abc
     %pubring foo.pub
     %secring foo.sec
     # Do a commit here, so that we can later print "done" :-)
     %commit
     %echo done
EOF

$gpg2 --verbose --batch --gen-key foo
```

But above thing does not generate any `foo.sec` file with secret key ring.

Comment: I removed your second question about searching an example -- multiple barely related questions per question/thread are discouraged on Stack Exchange, and it was unclear anyway. What kind of example are you after?

Comment: The GnuPG documentation [is extended by now](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=commitdiff;h=ca02a8b78fca8815388a859962584d75169ae3ee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in GnuPG 2, I'd expect only starting with GnuPG 2.1 (which moved the secret keyring into the public keyring). I added a [bug report](https://bugs.gnupg.org/gnupg/issue2400) describing the issue (which was [resolved on 2016-12-16 through extended documentation](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=commitdiff;h=ca02a8b78fca8815388a859962584d75169ae3ee)).

As a workaround, you could fall back to GnuPG 1.4, which should still be available as `gpg` (instead of `gpg2`). At least with GnuPG 1.4.20 I was able to have the secret key successfully being exported.

If you don't need the secret key exported to a separate file, just ommit `%pubring` and `%secring` to have the keys stored in your default GnuPG keyring. You could of course also export it using `gpg --export-secret-keys [keyid]` afterwards.